# Javascript check/validate that sum of three fields add up to 1

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a nutrition JavaScript calculator where the user enters a daily calorie intake and selects their percentage of carbohydrate, protein, and fat. The result is the percentage of calories and grams from each nutrient. I've got it working but...

As a math check/validation, I want to include some code that will add up the selected carbohydrate, protein, and fat percentages and ensure they equal exactly 1 (or 100%). If this is not true, then I want a little alert/error message to pop up so they know to go back and fix this before the "Calculate" button will work.

**Here is the relevant code for what I'm trying to ensure adds up to 1**

Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide.

I'm a relative novice with JS, so I'm not even really sure of the exact code I need to use in this case.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc (form) {
var C, P, F 

P=form.Protein.options[form.Protein.selectedIndex].value
F=form.Fat.options[form.Fat.selectedIndex].value
C=form.Carbohydrate.options[form.Carbohydrate.selectedIndex].value

}
</script>
```

Comment: `if (+P + +F + +C !== 1) { alert('not equal to 100%'); }`? The extra `+`s are to coerce to numbers.

Comment: I think being explicit and parsing them with either `parseFloat` or `Number` would be better than the extra `+`s

Comment: if (1-P-F-C >0) would also work had it not been for JS's float fun. So `var P=".10",F=".60", C=".20";
var sum = +(1-P-F-C).toFixed(2)
if (sum>0) console.log(sum,"not 100%")` This gives .89999999999: `var P=".10", F=".60", C=".20"
console.log(+P + +F + +C)`

Comment: @HereticMonkey `var P=".10", F=".60", C=".20";
console.log(+P + +F + +C)`

Comment: @mplungjan Meh, a comment is not the place to solve JavaScript's crazy number logic. It was just a hint. Also, that code still gives the right answer; `.9 !== 1` and `.899999999 !== 1` :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
function calc(form) {
    const errorEl = document.getElementById('error');

   // Clear the error before calculating the new value.
   errorEl.innerText = 'Your error message';

   const protein = form.Protein.options[form.Protein.selectedIndex].value;
   const fat = form.Fat.options[form.Fat.selectedIndex].value;
   const carbohydrate = form.Carbohydrate.options[form.Carbohydrate.selectedIndex].value;

   if (Number.isNaN(prtein) || Number.isNaN(fat) || Number.isNaN(carbohydrate)) {
       document.getElementById('error').innerText = 'Your error message';
       return;
   }

   const sum = parseFloat(protein) + parseFloat(fat) + parseFloat(carbohydrate);

   if (sum > 1) {
       document.getElementById('error').innerText = 'Your error message';
   }
}
```

And you also need an element with the `error` id in your form that will show the error message. For example `<p id="error"></p>`

Comment: Parsefloat. The numbers are < 1

Comment: `const protein = form.Protein.value;
   const fat = form.Fat.value;
   const carbohydrate = form.Carbohydrate.value;
   const sum = parseFloat(protein) + parseFloat(fat) + parseFloat(carbohydrate);`

No need to test isNaN because the person who wrote the dropdown is the one deciding to put numbers in it

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your input/suggestions. Good news is I was able to get if (+P + +F + +C !== 1) { alert('not equal to 100%'); } to work perfectly. However, I'm quite interested to get the other solution to work if it's better code (and for my own learning). 

Question: Do I put the const in front of my existing code and then add the rest of the code around it? Or do I create a separate entry for const protein = form...etc and add the other code? I think for me, it's just figuring out how to integrate the code with what I've got already in place. Thanks a million for your wisdom.

Comment: I would use `const` instead of `var` or `let` if the variable is reassigned. In your example, it's best to use `const protein = form...` because it will never be reassigned. I hope this answers your question.